# prevent direct access to PDF link for guest users

Tags: .htaccess, security, pdf, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a joomla site. And have some pdf files into the root of the website.

Is there a way to protect the DIRECT ACCESS to the pdf's for the GUESTS(public) users.. and allow for REGISTERED users?

I tried with htaccess(deny) but registered users can't view the pdf directly too..
Searched but didn't find nothing about this.. PLEASE can somebody help.

Thank you

Comment: You can't detect of the user is logged in or not with a htaccess file, it will require PHP for this. Start by writing a script to detect of the user is logged in or not, grab an array of PDF files in your root, detect if the files names are in the URL , and redirect accordingly. Each one of these tasks can be found via a simple Google search. If you run into a specific coding issue, post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use document management plug-in if you wont want to write your own php codes.SO, DOCman is a powerful document management solution for Joomla. You can check it from following link.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/10958

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called download.php

Add the following code to download.php file enclose with php tag

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

// Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();

$user    = JFactory::getUser();
$getfile = JRequest::getVar('file',null,'get','string');

if($getfile){

    if($user->get('id') == 0){
      die('permission denied');
    }


    $link = "/files/".$getfile.".pdf"; // Locate the pdf file
    $file = JPATH_SITE.$link;

    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

    $filename = $getfile.'.pdf';

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".urlencode($filename));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

    $fp = fopen($file, "r");

    while (!feof($fp))
    {
      echo fread($fp, 65536);
      flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

$app->close();
```

URL example :- www.example.com/download.php?file=filename

And make sure you have change the $link variable as you need.

Comment: That just helped me tremendously, thanks! Works even with Joomla 1.5. Don't forget to add the deny rule in the .htacess file.

Answer (score 0):

In .htacess file you have to add the following code

deny from all

And it should be located under the invoice folder where the pdf files is located.

If you use deny from all then file do not have download access for the particular directory where the htacess file is located.

To allow download access for registered user the below controller has to be called instead of direct file path url.

URL example :- www.example.com/index.php?option=com_temp&task=temp.downloadmypdf&file=filename

```
public function downloadmypdf(){

    $user    = JFactory::getUser();
    $getfile = JRequest::getVar('file');

    if($user->get('id') == 0){
      die('permission denied');
    }

    $link = "/invoice/".$getfile.".pdf";
    $file = JPATH_SITE.$link;

    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

    $filename = $getfile.'.pdf';

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".urlencode($filename));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

    $fp = fopen($file, "r");

    while (!feof($fp))
    {
      echo fread($fp, 65536);
      flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
    }
    fclose($fp);

    JFactory::getApplication()->close();
}
```

Credits goes to Ashlin rejo.

Comment: thank you. could you please tell me where I can add this function? in index.php of the template?

Comment: Can you please tell me how will you add the pdf file by manually or do you use any component to save the file.